# react redirect page on timeOut

Tags: reactjs, redirect, timer

I am trying to redirect a page using React upon a setTimeOut. Still new to developing in general and very new to React so I'm a bit lost. Below is what I have so far...

```
componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            ???????????('/')
        }, 1000)
    }
```

Comment: You can look into https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start to adding routing to your application. Good luck!

Comment: `location.href = "http://youurl.com"`

Comment: @Sagivb.g : Doesn't that re-render the entire react application.

Comment: It will post to a new route yeah

Comment: For client side routing you can use react-router

Answer (score 6):

managed to figure it out.

```
componentWillMount(){
        setTimeout(() => { 
            this.props.history.push('/');
        }, 5000)
    }
```